# Create dictionary with length of string as key and string as value

Tags: python, string, dictionary, string-length

I have a list with random strings, as the one below:

```
strings =  ["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas"]
```

What I want is a dictionary with `len` of those strings (non unique, linear as they are in the list) as keys, and strings as values. Seems banal, but I am trying to do this in one line, find a nicer way to write it.

I tried this:

```
dict_of_len = {len(element):element for element in strings}
```

but somehow I get this as an output:

```
{4: 'libe', 7: 'abigail', 5: 'theta', 3: 'zas'}
```

len(dict_of_len) equals 4. What am I doing wrong?

What I would like to have is this:

```
{4: 'zone', 7: 'abigail', 5: 'theta', 4: 'form', 4: 'libe', 3: 'zas'}
```

Comment: dict key should be unique

Comment: That actually explains everything, thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dict` keys must be unique, a better alternative solution to your problem is storing lengths as keys (as you did before) and lists of strings with that length as values, you can do this using `itertools.groupby` (which requires that the data be sorted by the criteria it will be grouped by):

```
strings =  ["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas"] 

from itertools import groupby

dict_of_len = {k: list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(strings, key = len), len)}

print(dict_of_len)
```

Output:

```
{3: ['zas'], 4: ['zone', 'form', 'libe'], 5: ['theta'], 7:['abigail']}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the `groupby` solution, which requires pre-sorting, you can use a `defaultdict` or use `setdefault` to concisely accumulate a list of values:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dict_of_len = defaultdict(list)
for str in strings:
    dict_of_len[len(str)].append(str)
```

Or, using the older idiom:

```
dict_of_len = {}
for str in strings:
    dict_of_len.setdefault(len(str), []).append(str)
```

But there's nothing wrong with the `groupby` solution as long as you don't mind sorting.

Answer (score 0):

i use this:

```
dict_of_len = {element:len(element) for element in strings}
```

Comment: That would make a dictionary where the keys are strings and the values are lengths, which isn't what the OP asked for